# Calculate the probability $P(V^2-4UW>0)$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, discrete-mathematics, probability-distributions

> $U,V,W \sim R(0,1)$ are independent (notation: the given random
>   variables are equally distributed in interval zero to one).
>
> The density of $UW$ is $f_{UW}(t)=\left\{\begin{matrix}-\ln t, \text{
> if }t \in (0,1)\\ 0 \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\text{ else.
> }\end{matrix}\right.$
>
> Calulate the probability $P(V^2-4UW>0).$

As hint there is $$P(UW < y) = \int P(UW <y \mid W = w) f_W(w) dw$$

But I have another idea. I want calculate $P(V^2)$ and $P(4UW)$ seperately first. And then the total probabiliy in the end. Is this going to be well? I have done it for $P(X=V^2):$

$$P(X \leq x) = P((-\ln t)^2 \leq x) = P(-\ln t \leq \sqrt{x}) = P(\ln t \geq -\sqrt{x}) = P(t \geq e^{-\sqrt{x}})$$

$$F_X(x) = \int_{e^{-\sqrt{x}}}^{1}dt = 1-e^{-\sqrt{x}}$$

$$f(x) = \frac{d}{dx}\left(1-e^{-\sqrt{x}}\right)= \frac{e^{-\sqrt{x}}}{2\sqrt{x}}$$

Then do the same for $P(4UW)$, substract each other and done?

Comment: Your notation $P(V^2)$ is the CDF of $V^2$ I think? Not standard but okay. And no, subtracting each other is not the right thing.

Comment: Your calculation for $P(X \leq x)$ is not right.

Comment: @Falrach What's wrong with it?

Comment: $P(X\leq x) = \sqrt{x}$. The first and the second equation are wrong. It doesn't make sense to use $-\ln(t)$ here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that this works. Start with 
$$\Bbb{P}(V^2 - 4UW > 0) = \Bbb{P}\left(UW < \frac{V^2}{4}\right) = \int_0^1\Bbb{P}(UW < \frac{v^2}{4})f_V(v)dv$$
For calculation of $\Bbb{P}(UW < \frac{v^2}{4})$ use that you know the density of $UW$.